# Peer-to-Peer (P2P) Networking Decentralization

Tags: internet, peering

How does P2P networking locate peers in the network if there is no centralized point to look up IP addresses of the individual computers in the network. Assuming there was no domain to use to do an NSLookup, how exactly do they locate each other.

For example, if a developer created a P2P network that they wanted to be 100% independent of any domain authority, governmental authority or major internet backbone providers from blocking, how could that be accomplished?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a domain, but you need some sort of directory to find other users.  The directory itself could be decentralized with redundancy.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask about that on [su].

Answer (score 1):

In the case of bittorrent DHT, there *are* anchor points.

What you are describing is a classic bootstrap paradox. How do I find other nodes if I don't know any nodes in the network? You either have to be told one (eg. remember the peers you'd previously used, and hope at least one is still valid), or there has to be a static entry point (i.e. domain name, well-known anycast/multicast address, etc.)

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnutella#Design